# Can I conditionally provide a default implementation of a trait function?

Tags: rust

I have the following trait:

```rust
trait MyTrait {
    type A;
    type B;

    fn foo(a: Self::A) -> Self::B;

    fn bar(&self);
}
```

There are other functions like `bar` that must be always implemented by the user of the trait.

I would like to give `foo` a default implementation, but only when the type `A = B`.

Pseudo-Rust code:

```rust
impl??? MyTrait where Self::A = Self::B ??? {
    fn foo(a: Self::A) -> Self::B {
        a
    }
}
```

This would be possible:

```rust
struct S1 {}

impl MyTrait for S1 {
    type A = u32;
    type B = f32;

    // `A` is different from `B`, so I have to implement `foo`
    fn foo(a: u32) -> f32 {
        a as f32
    }

    fn bar(&self) {
        println!("S1::bar");
    }
}

struct S2 {}

impl MyTrait for S2 {
    type A = u32;
    type B = u32;

    // `A` is the same as `B`, so I don't have to implement `foo`,
    // it uses the default impl

    fn bar(&self) {
        println!("S2::bar");
    }
}
```

Is that possible in Rust?

Comment: While trying to answer, I ran into [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55630220/conflicting-implementations-of-trait) which might be of interest.

Comment: Does the function in trait which doesn't either take `self` (or reference to it) or return `Self` ever make sense?

Comment: @Cerberus I guess it wouldn't, but this was just simplified example. I will edit it to make more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extending [user31601's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55628849/155423) and using the remark from Sven Marnach's comment, here's an implementation of the trait with additional functions using the "delegate methods" pattern:

```rust
trait MyTrait {
    type A;
    type B;

    fn foo(a: Self::A) -> Self::B;
    fn bar();
}

trait MyTraitId {
    type AB;
    fn bar_delegate();
}

impl<P> MyTrait for P
where
    P: MyTraitId,
{
    type A = P::AB;
    type B = P::AB;

    fn foo(a: Self::A) -> Self::B {
        a
    }
    fn bar() {
        <Self as MyTraitId>::bar_delegate();
    }
}

struct S2;

impl MyTraitId for S2 {
    type AB = i32;
    fn bar_delegate() {
        println!("bar called");
    }
}

fn main() {
    <S2 as MyTrait>::bar(); // prints "bar called"
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ff5bf6aa207d3cc0a5cf630adaeb66ba)

Answer (score 5):

You can provide a default implementation in the trait definition itself by introducing a redundant type parameter:

```
trait MyTrait {
    type A;
    type B;

    fn foo<T>(a: Self::A) -> Self::B
    where
        Self: MyTrait<A = T, B = T>,
    {
        a
    }
}
```

This default implementation can be overridden for individual types. However, the specialized versions will inherit the trait bound from the definition of `foo()` on the trait so you can only actually *call* the method if `A == B`:

```
struct S1;

impl MyTrait for S1 {
    type A = u32;
    type B = f32;

    fn foo<T>(a: Self::A) -> Self::B {
        a as f32
    }
}

struct S2;

impl MyTrait for S2 {
    type A = u32;
    type B = u32;
}

fn main() {
    S1::foo(42);  // Fails with compiler error
    S2::foo(42);  // Works fine
}
```

Rust also has an [unstable impl specialization feature](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1210-impl-specialization.md), but I don't think it can be used to achieve what you want.

Comment: why did you add 'Additional methods' in the question again? Is that really important here?

Comment: @hellow It _may_ very well be important. Case in point, the fixed version of the code in the other answer actually works for the case that the aren't any further methods, but becomes cumbersome otherwise.

Comment: Thank you, but this solution doesn't work for me for the reason you already described - it is not possible to call `foo` if `A != B`, even if you provide your own implementation of `foo`.

Answer (score 2):

Will this suffice?:

```rust
trait MyTrait {
    type A;
    type B;

    fn foo(a: Self::A) -> Self::B;
}

trait MyTraitId {
    type AB;
}

impl<P> MyTrait for P
where
    P: MyTraitId
{
    type A = P::AB;
    type B = P::AB;

    fn foo(a: Self::A) -> Self::B {
        a
    }
}

struct S2;

impl MyTraitId for S2 {
    type AB = i32;
}
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3128566f15b640154ba0305eba7d65df)

As noted, it'll bump into problems if `MyTrait` as other methods that `MyTraitId` can't provide an implementation for.

Comment: The issue is that there could be multiple `MyTraitId` implementations for any type `P`, so you would end up with multiple conflictin impls for `MyTrait`. It may be possible to get this working by making `T` an associated type of `MyTraitId` instead of a type parameter, but it would still only be a partial solution, since you will have to implement all methods of `MyTrait` in the blanket implementation.

Comment: Please don't post *untested* code. Instead use [the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/) to easily and quickly check your code. This makes your and our life much easier :)

Comment: This would work, but what if there are other functions in the trait that do not have default implementation? Originally I had comment indicating that there are other functions, now I edited my question and added second function to make it clear.