# Is it a compiler limitation that reports "conflicting implementations of trait" even though it's impossible for a type to implement a trait?

Tags: rust, traits

When attempting to answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55628334/trait-function-conditional-default-implementation), I wrote this code:

```
trait MyTrait {
    type A;
    type B;
}

trait WithFoo: MyTrait {
    fn foo(a: Self::A) -> Self::B;
}

impl<T, U: MyTrait<A = T, B = T>> WithFoo for U {
    fn foo(a: T) -> T {
        a
    }
}

struct S1;

impl MyTrait for S1 {
    type A = u32;
    type B = f32;
}

impl WithFoo for S1 {
    fn foo<T>(a: Self::A) -> Self::B {
        a as f32
    }
}

struct S2;

impl MyTrait for S2 {
    type A = u32;
    type B = u32;
}

fn main() {
    S1::foo(42);
    S2::foo(42);
}
```

[playground](https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=47d8849d433475bc06456dba7768dcc5)

This fails to compile with the following error:

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `WithFoo` for type `S1`:
  --> src/main.rs:23:1
   |
10 | impl<T, U: MyTrait<A = T, B = T>> WithFoo for U {
   | ----------------------------------------------- first implementation here
...
23 | impl WithFoo for S1 {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ conflicting implementation for `S1`
```

According to [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39161143/5397009) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45034077/5397009) this error occurs even though type `S1` doesn't fit the `impl` trait bounds when the compiler can't be sure that some future blanket `impl` would cause `S1` to suddenly match the bounds.

However in this case it is impossible that `S1` could ever implement `MyTrait` with `A == B` since it already implements `MyTrait` with `A != B`. Is the error a limitation of the current compiler implementation that might conceivably be lifted at some later point or is there something else I'm missing?